# Circumvent the sed backreference limit \1 through \9

Tags: regex, shell, sed, backreference

The sed manual clearly states that the available backreferences available for the replacement string in a substitute are numbered \1 through \9. I'm trying to parse a log file that has 10 fields.

I have the regex formed for it but the tenth match (and anything after) isn't accessible.

Does anyone have an elegant way to circumvent this limitation in KSH (or any language that perhaps I can port to shell scripting)?

Comment: You can use pretty much any scripting language that lets you write one-liners for this. `perl -pe 's/yourregexhere/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10/'`

Comment: It's quite possible that you can use a simpler regex that doesn't need that many backreferences. If you show some sample data and an example of the output you want, we can probably show you a simpler way.

Comment: sounds like a job for `awk` -- field 10 is `$10`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you user `perl -pe 's/(match)(str)/$2$1/g;'` in place of sed?  The way to circumvent the backreference limit is to use something other than sed.

Also, I suppose you could do your substitution in two steps, but I don't know your pattern so I can't help you out with how.

Comment: thank you this worked great. now i need to figure out how to generate patterns on the fly and run this command from a ksh script, but that's a question for another day.

Answer (score 7):

Split the stream with -e, as long as the replaced elements are with in the group that you split them with. When I did a date split so I could re-org the date-time into a string of 14 digits, I had to split the stream up 3 times.

```
echo "created: 02/05/2013 16:14:49" |  sed -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]*: \)//' -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(\/\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(\/\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\( \)/\5\1\3/' -e 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(\:\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\(\:\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\3\5/'
```

20130205161449

Comment: It's good to know you can split it like this, but in your example you didn't need to capture the parts you were throwing away. The following achieves the same effect (-E lets you drop the slashes before the parens): `sed -E -e 's/[[:alpha:]]*: ([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/\3\1\2\4\5\6/'`

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for a shell script solution - that means you're not limited to using just sed, correct?  Most shells support arrays, so perhaps you can parse the line into a shell array variable?  If need be, you could even parse the same line multiple times, extracting different bits of information on each pass.

Would that do?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `GNU awk`, You can do things with much more in control. For this you would be needing `match(source,/regex/,array)` construct.

Example:

Sample input for test:

```
 echo "$x"
p1=aaa,p2=bb,p3=cc,p4=dd,p5=ee,p6=ff,p7=gg,p8=hh,p9=ii,p10=jj
```

`sed` works fine till `\9` :

```
echo $x |sed -r 's/p1=([^,]+).*p2=([^,]+).*p3=([^,]+).*p4=([^,]+).*p5=([^,]+).*p6=([^,]+).*p7=([^,]+).*p8=([^,]+).*p9=([^,]+)(.*)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9/'
aaa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii
```

`sed` broke when `\10` is added, it is considered is `\1`+`0`.

```
echo $x |sed -r 's/p1=([^,]+).*p2=([^,]+).*p3=([^,]+).*p4=([^,]+).*p5=([^,]+).*p6=([^,]+).*p7=([^,]+).*p8=([^,]+).*p9=([^,]+).*p10=([^,]+)(.*)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 \10/'
aaa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii aaa0
```

`awk` to rescue when any back reference added more than 9 is added. Here 10th refrence is added:

```
echo "$x" |awk '{match($0,/p1=([^,]+).*p2=([^,]+).*p3=([^,]+).*p4=([^,]+).*p5=([^,]+).*p6=([^,]+).*p7=([^,]+).*p8=([^,]+).*p9=([^,]+).*p10=([^,]+)(.*)/,a);print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10]}'
aaa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a solution that doesn't require the use of regular expression backreferences. For example, if you have a simple field delimiter, use `split`, or even use awk for your processing instead of perl.