# Use sed to replace values in a csv column if a condition is met in another column

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a CSV file composed of several fields split by commas.

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
```

I have to change from lowercases to uppercases the values on column "name" when the column "sport" is shooting or judo. I can only use `sed`. I am using this command

```
sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)/\1,\U\2\E,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\shooting|judo,\9,\10,\11,\12/' athletesv2.csv
```

But it is not working, as it's just showing "shooting|judo" in all the rows.

How can I make these replacements?

Note that the output must be a .sed file, which has to be called using `sed -f script.sed athletes.csv`

In the output I need to keep the header.

I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Standard `sed` does not support case conversion. On which platform and/or `sed` version does this need to work?

Comment: In Ubuntu, I managed to do the case conversion, what i miss is setting the condition in a sed script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,shooting\|judo,/s/,[^,]*/\U&/' input_file
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A JESUS GARCIA,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,shooting,0,0,0,
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can use a GNU `sed`, you can use

```sh
rx='^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(shooting|judo),[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)$'
repl='\1,\U\2\E,\3'
sed -E "s/$rx/$repl/" athletes.csv
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/TpNnNf):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rx='^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(shooting|judo),[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)$'
repl='\1,\U\2\E,\3'

s='id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
132041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,shooting,0,0,0,'

sed -E "s/$rx/$repl/" <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
132041664,A JESUS GARCIA,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,shooting,0,0,0,
```

Notes:

- `^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(shooting|judo),[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)$` is a pattern that matches a whole string (`^` is the start of string and `$` matches the end of string) that captures Field 1 and 2 into separate groups and the rest of the string into Group 3. Field 8 pattern is hard-coded, `(shooting|judo)` either matches `shooting` or `judo`.
- `\U\2\E` in the replacement will put Group 2 value back in uppercase.

Note you [cannot use more than `\9` backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4318114/3832970) in sed, so you need to decrease their amount and group those groups that are not used.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. It works perfectly! However i need to create a sed script, it has to be run as sed -f script3.sed athletes.csv. in this sed script i need to add more conditions as: s/ESP/Spain/p s/DEN/Denmark/p ...

Comment: Then save the script in a file. Is it acceptakle to put `#!/usr/bin/sed -Ef` in the shebang?

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use `sed -E` you will basically have to backslash the parentheses and the `|` like in your original code.

Comment: There is no indication I cannot use sed -E, I will try this way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;x;s/[^,]*/\n&\n/8;/\n(shooting|judo)\n/{x;s/[^,]*/\U&/2;x};x' file
```

Make a copy of the current line.

Surround the copy of the eighth field by newlines and if that field contains either `shooting` or `judo`, uppercase the second field in the unadulterated version.